# how do I change the colour of the command button on a userform with vba after the button has completely executed the code?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, vba7

For example, the original colour of the text label of the button is black. I would like to change it to green after execution.n If someone can answer this more specifically for powerpoint vba, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: What kind of command button property do you think would affect the color of the font?  Have you tried setting any properties from your code?

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/button-color-and-text-change-on-click.597988/